# Как конвертировать строку в число?

Tags: c++

Допустим, есть строка (`string`, не `char`) `= "1234.55"`. Как конвертировать ее в полноценное вещественное число?

Comment: Нужно лишь немножко заглянуть в гугл:)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/convert-string-to-int-c

Comment: @Aleksandr: ...и получить ответы с `atoi`, за котрые надо драть задницу.

Answer (score 5):

Рекомендую воспользоваться функцией из стандартного пространства имён `std`, которая появилась в c++11:

```
double stod (const string&  str, size_t* idx = 0);
```

Подробную информацию по ней можно найти [тут](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/).

Answer (score 3):

Даже интересно прикинуть количество способов...

```
string s; double d;

1.  d = stod(s);
2.  d = atof(s.c_str());
3.  sscanf(s.c_str(),"%lf",&d);
4.  strtod(s.c_str(),0);
5.  istringstream(s) >> d;
```

Кто больше? :)

Comment: Смотря что считать "способом". Если способ не продоставляет возможностей контроля за ошибками (переполнение, например), то считать его "способом" весьма трудно. Т.е. то `atof` и `sscanf` не считаются - они порождают неопределенное поведение при переполнении.

Comment: @AnT `sscanf` дожен при переполнении выдать `inf`, если я правильно помню, конечно. У нас же в условии - плавающая точка. Про `atof` не скажу, yt помню точно... но думаю, что внутри у него то же, что и в `sscanf` :)

Comment: И у `sscanf` и у `atof` - неопределенное поведение при переполнении. В этом смысле у них внутри действительно все одинаково. `inf` гарантируется именно и только `strtod`. У `sscanf` есть еще одна тонкость - его поведение должно быть эквивалентно `fscanf`. А `fscanf` в своб очередь должен быть реализован так, чтобы возвращать обратно в поток не более одного символа. У `strtod` такого ограничения нет. Поэтому последователности символов, принимаемые `sscanf` и `strtod` могут отличаться. (В данном случае, однако, последнее скорее всего неактуально.)

Comment: @AnT А можно какую-то ссылку? просто поискал - ни в ту, ни в другую сторону ничего не нашел...

Comment: Неопределенное поведение при переполнении: `fscanf` "7.21.6.2/9 [...] An input item is defined as the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed any specified field width and which is, or is a prefix of, a matching input sequence." "7.21.6.2/10 [...] the input item  is converted to a type appropriate to the conversion specifier [...] the
result of the conversion is placed in the object [...] If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.".

Comment: `atof`: "7.22.1/1 The functions atof, atoi, atol, and atoll [...]If the value of the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: Что касается разницы в парсинге, то оно следует из вышепроцитированного 7.21.6.2/9 и в стандарте об этом есть сноска "285) fscanf pushes back at most one input character onto the input stream. Therefore, some sequences that are acceptable to strtod, strtol, etc., are unacceptable to fscanf." А далее: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334399/what-is-the-result-of-strtod3ex-end-supposed-to-be-what-about-sscanf, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425730/difference-between-scanf-and-strtol-strtod-in-parsing-numbers, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c/xFyJWWWHAyA

Comment: @AnT Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ну допустим:

```
float i = boost::lexical_cast<float>("123.321");
```